# If a charge comes into existence, and there is another charge 20 light years away(which existed for eternity), what will be the interaction?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, speed-of-light, charge, interactions

Our physics teacher just taught us a bit about electric fields, and why the concept was invented. He said that if a charge comes into existence, another charge won’t feel its effect instantaneously, rather the field will travel with the speed of light and forces will happen when the field reaches the other charge. 
But if a charge comes into existence, let’s call it particle 1, while another charge has been 20 light years away from that point in space from a long time, let’s call this one particle 2, what will the interaction be like? 
 My best guess was that particle 1 will feel the effect of particle 2 as soon as it comes in existence, while particle 2 will the effect from particle 1 after 20 years. 
I simply don’t know, please help?

Comment: Depends on time period $\Delta t$ which charge 2 resides in that place. If $\Delta t >= 20 \,\text{years}$, then charge 2 electromagnetic field will fill space in charge 1 location, So charge 1 will feel charge 2 instantly. But it requires yet another 20 years for charge 1 electromagnetic field to reach particle 2.

Comment: Yeah I suppose that would be fine. If one charge, q1 has been there for a long time, and a neutral particle is separated into two charges, on of which is q2, and taken very far away very fast. I just want to know, since the field of q1 has been spread throughout the universe, while the field of q2 has just started happening. Will q2 start feeling the effect of q1 instantly, or will they both feel each other's electrostatic forces at the same time(Newton's 3rd Law)? Consider that they are 20 light years away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a cork is floating on a still pond and then you drop a brick into the pond several metres away, does the cork start bobbing about as soon as the brick touches the water? Or does it have to wait until the waves reach it?

So the remote charge has to wait on the electric field to propagate from the initial charge.

By the way, a single charge can't *come into existence* on its own - there has to be an equal and opposite charge as well (Law of Conservation of Charge).

Comment: If we think of this like a trampoline, then the cork’s been there for a lot of time, it’s bending the fabric(By the way, can I think of fields like this?), and when I drop a brick, it feels the effect of the cork instantly, but the cork will feel the effect of the brick after the waves reach it. Is this a suitable analogy? I know that the cork will feel the brick’s effect after a certain time, but does the brick feel the effect instantly, as the fabric is already bent?

Comment: The cork-on-a-pond analogy was to get across the idea of a change in a field propagating across space. If you want to go with a bending-of-spacetime view then you still have the propagation of the distortion of the trampoline - the cork doesn't feel the brick _instantly_. It has to wait for the distortion to arrive.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I still have one more question though.In the cork-brick(or the two charges case, whatever) case, thinking via the bending of space time analogy, the brick feels the effect(force due to the cork) of the cork instantly, while the cork has to wait a bit to feel the force due to the brick's presence. What happened to Newton's third law in this case? I mean, since the electrostatic force acts in a pair, shouldn't both feel each other's effect simultaneously? How is one feeling the other's presence individually? Or is the third law not valid here for some reason?

Comment: The brick doesn't feel the cork instantly - not really. It feels the cork _as it used to be_ when the brick arrives. Put it this way: the brick arrives and observes that spacetime is already bent by the cork. But, suppose the cork immediately vanishes! Does spacetime straighten out immediately at the brick's position? No - it has to wait on the _absence_ of the cork propagating to its location. By the way, all this appearing and disappearing of mass-energy is a bit non-physical so I wouldn't take it too seriously.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was really comprehensive.